# Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'String!' - Swift with Parse

Tags: string, swift

After updating my code to swift 1.2 i stuck on one point

```
var Question:String!
var Answere:String!
var Answeres:[String]!
var ObjectIDsArray:[String]!
var ButtonNumber:String!
var ObjectIDsArrayCount:Int!


var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "AddonQuiz")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(QuestionID){
            (ObjectHolder : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                self.Question = ObjectHolder["ImageLink"] as! String
                self.Answeres = ObjectHolder["Answeres"] as! Array
                self.Answere = ObjectHolder["Right"] as! String




                if self.Answeres.count > 0 {
```

With the errors

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'String!'
Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type '[String]!'
Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'String!'
```

for Lines

```
self.Question = ObjectHolder["ImageLink"] as! String
self.Answeres = ObjectHolder["Answeres"] as! Array
self.Answere = ObjectHolder["Right"] as! String
```

Any work around for that?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus can you explain me once a work around for that?

Comment: ObjectHolder : PFObject?, error : NSError? you mean in that part like "ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error : NSError!" ? this does not work for me

Comment: added a update on top to show how i declare them

Comment: You should also name them starting with a lowercase letter (Swift convention)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus would it be possible to post once a answer to check that?

Comment: @matt can you show in a answer once how?

Comment: he probably means ObjectHolder : PFObject!

Comment: well this gives me the error:

Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type '(String, (PFObject!, NSError?) -> Void)'

Comment: so unwrap it using if let ObjectHolder = ObjectHolder { ... }

Comment: can you post once the full "line" with the if let @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Just wrap those 3 lines inside  { ... }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if let ObjectHolder = ObjectHolder { 
    self.Question = ObjectHolder["ImageLink"] as! String
    self.Answeres = ObjectHolder["Answeres"] as! Array
    self.Answere = ObjectHolder["Right"] as! String
}
```